# How to configure Spring BeanPostProcessor to get invoked only for a defined set of spring managed beans

Tags: java, spring

How to configure Spring **BeanPostProcessor** to get invoked only for a defined set of spring managed beans using xml configuration or annotation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I doubt if you can control purely by xml configuration/annotation. You can however control it within the code of the BeanPostProcessor:

```
public Object postProcessBeforeInitialization(Object bean, String beanName) {
    if (thisBeanIsOfConcernToMe(bean, beanName){
      doPostProcessTasks()...
    }
}
```

If this BeanProcessor is not under your control, then overriding the bean and delegating to the parent for certain custom conditions would be another way to go:

```
public MyBeanProcessor extends NotUnderControlBeanPostProcessor {
....
    public Object postProcessBeforeInitialization(Object bean, String beanName) {
        if (thisBeanIsOfConcernToMe(bean, beanName){
          return super.postProcessBeforeInitialization(bean, beanName)
        }else{
             return bean;
        }
    } 
}
```